# How can I play a wav file in Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight

How can I play a wav file in Silverlight 3.File is on other web site.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the MediaElement to play a sound file. To be honest, I was unable to get Silverlight to play a .WAV file and had to convert it to WMA. But it may have just been an unsupported codec.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like SL2 don't support wav playback. But in SL3 wav playback is support.

I hope this can help.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wavmss

http://blogs.msdn.com/gillesk/archive/2009/03/23/playing-back-wave-files-in-silverlight.aspx

Regards.